# Why different results with XPath 1.0 and RCurl vs httr, using substring-before an expression

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping, httr

When I use XPath 1.0's substring-before or -after in an expression, something happens that makes my subsequent xmlValue call throw an error.  The code below shows that the XPath expression works fine with httr, but then doesn't work with RCurl.

```
require(XML)
require(httr)
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.cottonbledsoe.com/CM/Custom/TOCContactUs.asp", useInternal = TRUE)
(string <- xpathSApply(doc, "substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')", xmlValue, trim = TRUE))


require(RCurl)
fetch <- GET("http://www.cottonbledsoe.com/CM/Custom/TOCContactUs.asp")
contents <- content(fetch)
locsnodes <- getNodeSet(contents, "//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p")  
sapply(locsnodes, xmlValue)

[1] "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n Phone: 432-897-1440\r\n Toll Free: 866-721-6665\r\n Fax: 432-682-3672"
```

The code above works OK, but I want to use substring-before it to clean up the result like this:

```
[1] "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n "

locsnodes <- getNodeSet(contents, "substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')")  
sapply(locsnodes, xmlValue)

Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "character"
```

How can I use `substring-` and also RCurl, because RCurl is the chosen package for a more complicate operation used later?

Thank you for any guidance (or better way to achieve what I want

Comment: You could just do an `xpathSApply(contents, "substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)`

Comment: The function call is redundant here so `doc["substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')"]` would do the trick.

Comment: You don't use httr anywhere?

Comment: @hadley.  I am actually scraping 600+ sites and I use httr in the function that runs through all the steps for downloading the html, parsing it and then running the XPath expression.  I realize now, belatedly, that I should have explained that I need to avoid R regex solutions because that would require lots of one-off coding.  If I can do it in XPath, I am far better off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fun` argument in `xpathSApply` or indeed `getNodeSet` is only called if a node set is returned. In your case a character string is being returned and the function is ignored:

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)
doc <- htmlParse("http://www.cottonbledsoe.com/CM/Custom/TOCContactUs.asp")
locsnodes <- getNodeSet(doc
                        , "substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')")  
> locsnodes
[1] "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n "

> str(locsnodes)
 chr "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n "
```

The `fun` argument is not being used here in `xpathSApply`

```
> xpathSApply(doc, "substring-before(//div[@id = 'contactInformation']//p, 'Phone')"
+             , function(x){1}
+ )
[1] "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n "
```

as your xpath is not returning a node set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach using the
[rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) package. I think you're
generally better off doing string manipulation in R, rather than in
xpath

```
library(rvest)

contact <- html("http://www.cottonbledsoe.com/CM/Custom/TOCContactUs.asp")

contact %>%
  html_node("#contactInformation p") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub(" Phone.*", "", .)
#> [1] "500 West Illinois, Suite 300\r\n Midland, Texas 79701\r\n"
```

Comment: Would agree that avoiding string manipulation in xpath if possible is sensible.